# is this undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I found the following code in our codebase. My colleague thinks that it's ok but it seems suspiciously like UB. Is it UB or not?

```
class A {
   //some stuff
};

class B : public A {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}

void foo( std::vector<A>& a ) {

   std::vector<B> b;
   for(size_t i = 0 ; i < a.size(); ++i ){
      b.push_back( *(B*)(&a[i]) );
   }

   //remove some elements from b

   for(size_t i = 0 ; i < b.size(); ++i ){
      a.push_back( *(A*)(&b[i]) );
   }

}
```

Comment: It appears so, `*(B*)(&a[i])` reads data beyond `a[i]`'s memory. For the last element, you'll read data beyond memory you own.

Comment: `push_back` will copy an `A` using `B`'s copy semantics, which (unless you're not copying a, b or c) is definitely going to read uninitialised memory.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Isn't the derefencing already UB?

Comment: @bennofs yes, the first `*`....

Comment: This can't be in the production code. This is madness uncovered.

Comment: @SChepurin it's not yet in production code - just in our internal builds :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is undefined behavior. The real object, inside the original vector, is an `A`, not a `B`, so the cast is incorrect and you will get undefined behavior.

The most common result from that code would be either incorrect data (the members of `B` not present in `A` are read from the next object in the vector if present, or from the following memory locations) or a crash (if it happens to be the last element, there was no extra space reserved in the original vector and the read happen to extend to a memory page that is protected.

Comment: Is it necessarily true if B's copy constructor does not copy a, b or c though? Then I can't see a read outside allocated memory. (No, I'm definitely not advocating this code, just wondering about the technicalities)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: In the code above the copy constructor is implicitly defined and it *will* attempt the copy. In a different case you might implement a copy constructor that does not touch those members, but that would be awkward to say the least... why are those members not important? If you want to support copying from an `A` object you can just implement a constructor that takes an `A`.

Comment: True about the default copy constructors, did not consider that. Just asking to draw the line clearly between `UB` and `HHC` (horrible horrible code) :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Well, with the standard at hand, it is UB. The `static_cast` from a pointer to base to a pointer to derived is undefined if the pointer does not refer to the base subobject of a derived object. 5.2.9p11 *[...]If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object
of type D. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.*

Comment: the original reason I'm asking is because my colleague told me it was harmless because (according to him) the only problem would be that the extra data would contain garbage values, which are indeed never read in the program. 
So just to be clear: the mere fact of attempting to read data from un-allocated memory can crash the program?

Comment: @lezebulon With hardware supporting memory protection or virtual memory, most certainly, yes.

Comment: @lezebulon: Yes, it can. In the worst case you have a vector buffer that takes a multiple of the page size, and it is full. Then the three extra `int` fall in a different page that might not be mapped into your process or might be protected.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes, it's undefined behavior.

Removing the vectors makes this clearer:

```
void foo( A a ) {
  B b;
  b = *(B*)(&a);
  a = *(A*)(&b);
}
```

The above version is equivalent to yours in terms of the memory issues involved. The last statement - the assignment to `a` - is actually fine. It's a polymorphic upcast, and in fact you don't even need all the extra casting. This is fine:

```
a = *&b;
```

The first assignment - to `b` - is undefined. You are trying an illegal polymorphic downcast. This may be harmless, and all the extra casting will force the compiler to accept it. But it is definitely undefined behavior.

In general if you are using C-style casts with C++ classes, you're in trouble. The right way to try this type of downcast is with dynamic_cast:

```
b = *(dynamic_cast<B*>(&a));
```

However this will fail at run-time because `&a` is not a `B*`, and in fact, my compiler gives a warning that what I'm doing is ridiculous:

```
warning: dynamic_cast of 'A a' to 'class B*' can never succeed
```